# Printing out ObservableList<ObsevableList<String>>items from a tableview one item at a time

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have Board model that I map to a tableView.  I can printout the entire selection, but I am trying to print out each line in the selection with special formatting. 
Here is the model

```
public class Board (String pieceno, String avge, String lpte, String lptloc, String grade) {

    String PcNo;
    String AvgE;
    String LptE;
    String LptLoc;
    String Grade;

    public Board( {
        this.PcNo = pieceno;
        this.AvgE = avge;
        this.LptE = lpte;
        this.LptLoc = lptloc;
        this.Grade = grade;
    }

    public String getPcNo() {
        return PcNo;
    }
    public void setPcNo(String pcno) {
        PcNo = pcno;
    }
    pubic String getAvgE() {
        return AvgE;
    }
    public void setAvgE(String avge) {
        AvgE = avge;
    }
    public String getLptE() {
        return LptE;
    }
    public void setLptE(String lpte) {
        LptE = lpte;
    }
    public String getLptLoc() {
        return LptLoc;
    }
    public void setLptLoc(String lptloc) {
        LptLoc = lptloc;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return Grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(String gr) {
        Grade = gr; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return getPcNo() + "," + getAvgE() + "," + getLptE()
                         + "," + getLptLoc() + "," + getGrade() + "\n";
    }
```

}

Now here is the code for tableView and selection of multiple rows.

```
TableView tableView = new TableView();
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);


TableColumn pcNoCol = new TableColumn();
pcNoCol.setText("pcNo");
pcNoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("pcNo"));
tableView.getColumns().add(pcNoCol);

TableColumn avgECol = new TableColumn();
avgECol.setText("avgE");
avgECol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("avgE"));
tableView.getColumns().add(avgECol);

TableColumn lptECol = new TableColumn();
lptECol.setText("lptE");
lptECol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lptE"));
tableView.getColumns().add(lptECol);

TableColumn lptLocCol = new TableColumn();
lptLocCol.setText("lptLoc");
lptLocCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lptLoc"));
tableView.getColumns().add(lptLocCol);

TableColumn gradeCol = new TableColumn();
gradeCol.setText("grade");
gradeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("grade"));
tableView.getColumns().add(gradeCol);

//Bindings. 
p.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());  
veil.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());  
p.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());  
tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());
```

Now the mouse event that grabs the rows and prints out selecteditems is

```
   tableView.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>>selectedItems = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        //selectedItems.forEach(selecteditem -> System.out.println(selecteditem));
        System.out.println(selectedItems);
    });
```

The code works, but Instead of println(selectedItems) I wish to print out each individual selected item,  I try the line that is commented out above the foreach line. but I get the following error.

```
Executing /home/jimbo/NetBeanProjects/AccountFXFrontEnd/dist/run12421/AccountFXFrontEnd.jar usring platform /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java
Exception in thread"JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: accountfxfrontend model Board cannot be cast  to javafx.collections.ObservableList
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach Iterable.java.75
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do in order to print out each item rather than the collection?  Thanks.

I should be obvious that I am new to javafx and collections I appreciate the help ..

jimbo

Comment: What is your datatype that you are binding here?  tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());

Answer (score 0):

You should really start using type parameters, like `TableView<Board>`. It will help to avoid such mistakes. So, this:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

returns `ObservableList<Board>`, not `ObservableList<ObservableList<String>>`. Hence the exception when using `forEach`, as it tries to cast `Board` to `ObservableList`. You don't get it with `System.out.println(selectedItems)`, because in this case there is no type casting, `println` just operates with `Object`. By the way, if you use:

```
ObservableList selectedItems = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

it will work with `forEach` as well, because, again, it will be operating with `Object`.